# Write to log if user is in array in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Can anyone explain why the following isn't working?

I want to write `Blocked user` to `log.txt` if `$user` is in the array `$blockedusers`

```
$blockedusers = array("USER1", "USER2");
$user = "USER1";
foreach ($user as $blockedusers) {
    $file = 'log.txt';
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    $current .= 'Blocked user' . "\n";
    file_put_contents($file, $current);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Also, `ini_set('display_errors', '1'); error_reporting(E_ALL);` to avoid blank pages.

Comment: My bad @fedorqui but still it's not doing what I want it to do :/

Comment: You're using `foreach()` wrong. Try using `in_array()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A loop is not required if you just want to check if a particular user is in the `$blockedusers` array. There's a built-in function for that purpose  and it's recommended to use that.

Using [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array):

```
if (in_array($user, $blockedusers)) {
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    $current .= 'Blocked user: '.$user."\n";
    file_put_contents($file, $current);
}
```

Or, if you have an array of users, and you want to check if any of them are in the blocked list, you can do the following:

```
$users = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
foreach ($users as $user) {
    if (in_array($user, $blockedusers)) {
        $current = file_get_contents($file);
        $current .= 'Blocked user' . "\n";
        file_put_contents($file, $current);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the way to go! :)